# Passing the output of one function to another function

Tags: r, opencpu

I have code that runs fine on the desktop R, but not on my desktop when I use openCPU.  The offending line is:

```
out.seg<-segmented(glm.out2,seg.Z=~period,k=1,psi=c(4))
```

...and I get the error:

```
HTTP error 400: object 'glm.out2' not found
In call:
eval(expr, envir, enclos)
```

...however, I know that glm.out2 exists and I can retrieve its coefficients in both desktop and openCPU when I insert a stop command to display the coefficients.
I think I am missing how openCPU passes differently the output of one function to another function.

thanks

bob